# Setting the value of a combobox with datasource in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, combobox

I have an issue where the combobox does not set to the binding value within a list view.

As you can see from the screenshot below, the other values are populating from the binding correctly. Is it something to do with the fact it is a combobox opposed to a textbox/label?

[image]

The admin combo has two options, true or false. The datatable which the listview (code below) is bound to contains the values "True" and "False" for the various records.

```
<ListView Name="grdUsers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="6,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="225" Width="289"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PK}" Header="PK" Width="30">
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="115">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="115"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Group" Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MemberGroup}" Width="45"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Admin" Width="70">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=IsAdmin}"  Width="55">
                                <ComboBoxItem>True</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>False</ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

It is the last item within here that is the issue, I have tried changing the binding to selectedItem and all sorts.

So, how do I bind the datatable value to the combo and why does it not work for the combo and does for the textboxes?

Thanks

Comment: Is `IsAdmin` a boolean property? if your options are True or False why don't you use a CheckBox instead?

Comment: It is coming through as a string "True" or "False". I have tried this which also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `ComboBox` has 2 items of `ComboBoxItem` type and not `String` and this means that `SelectedItem` will also be of a `ComboBoxItem` type. Try something like this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=IsAdmin}" Width="55">
   <ComboBox.Items>
      <sys:String>True</sys:String>
      <sys:String>False</sys:String>
   </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

for this to work you'll nee to define `sys:` namespace like so:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but there is still no default value being displayed when the form is loaded. The dropdown items come out fine but the relative values do not.

Comment: @Jacooobley, I've update my answer. Try using `SelectedItem` instead of `Text` and be aware that this will be case sensitive

Comment: This works fine! Thanks very much :-) So it was to do with the type of comboItem I was using. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If `IsAdmin` is a string containing only `True` or `False`, you can simply bind it to a `CheckBox` using a `StringToBoolean` converter:

```
public class StringToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value.ToString() == "True") ? true : false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Use this converter as a resource

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StringToBooleanConverter x:Key="strToBoolConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And use it in the binding

```
          <GridViewColumn Header="Admin" Width="70">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsAdmin, Converter={StaticResource strToBoolConverter}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: I'm rather new to XAML, so would the top code snippet need its own class within the solution?

Comment: `StringToBooleanConverter` is a class of it's own. Depending on it's namespace you'll have to include the relevant using statement. For example I created it under the namespace `WpfApplication4`, so I added the statement `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"` to my xaml and used it as `<local:StringToBooleanConverter ....`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to fix your problem. Personally, I would prefer to use actual `bool` properties to represent Boolean values. Using this method, you'd need to `Bind` to a `bool` collection containing your `true` *and* `false` values in it and then `Bind` your `IsAdmin` property (if it were of type `bool`) to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` instead.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding BoolCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding IsAdmin}" />
```

Of course, you'll need to add this `BoolCollection` into whatever object that you have bound to the control, or change your `Binding`... you *could* also create `bool` items like this:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
<ComboBox.Items>
    <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
    <System:Boolean>False</System:Boolean>
</ComboBox.Items>
```

An alternative method has been alluded to by @dkozl, although I believe that you still need to `Bind` from your `IsAdmin` property to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` instead of the `Text` value.